# Remote boot and login with mac and iPhone?

Tags: iphone, mac, remote-login

I need (free) software to login to my iMac from my iPod.  TeamViewer works but the iMac puts itself to sleep. Are there any programs that can turn on my iMac remotely? Alternatively, are tere any settings that I can change to keep my iMac on at all times and ensure constant availability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check [Caffeine](http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/) out. It (temporarily) prevents your Mac to go to sleep by an one-click icon on your menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

If you really mean "keep my iMac on at all times", go to System Preferences | Energy Saver and set the computer sleep time to "never".

But for your first question, try enabling Wake On LAN, (it's called "Wake for Ethernet network access" on my system - 10.6.3) and forwarding UDP port 9 from your router to the iMac. Then you should be able to visit [this page](http://www.dslreports.com/wakeup) from your iPhone to wake the iMac. You'll need to know your iMac's MAC address, and you'll need to know its external IP address.  If it's IP isn't static then you'll need have set up some means to publish it, or use a forwarder like Dynamic DNS.

Note that the iMac either needs to be connected via Ethernet or to be new enough to have implemented Wake on Wireless LAN.  (Mine is neither so I haven't been able to test this - sorry.)

Comment: it is a new iMac, late 2009 model. would that have wireless lan wake?

Comment: I don't know what models got the feature and I don't have one here to look, but if it has, I'd expect you'd see a checkbox for it on the system preferences page I referred to above.

Comment: Good answer, but caffeine worked for me. I will look into this more when I am up to it. +1